# estou tendo dificuldade para mudar a cor deste icone Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, input

eu estou usando o Ionic e Angular em um projeto e gostaria de mudar a cor do ícone que vem padrão dentro do ion-input quando esta no type Date, já tentei o básico como css por exemplo color background-color e ate mesmo o webkit-calendar[image: ion-input type Datetime]

**no caso esse ícone que esta em branco**

meu código html esta assim

```
<div class="m">
<ion-label translate>news.list.title.startDate</ion-label>
<div class="loh lo1 h-end">
<ion-item class="s">
<ion-input
name="startDate"
[(ngModel)]="news.startPostDate"
type="datetime-local"
class="p0"
></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</div>
</div>
```

no caso tentei adicionar um ícone direto do ionic só que ele só permiti abrir o input quando você clica nesse que já vem padrão, o ícone que eu adiciono acaba ficando do lado deste e não é possível clicar nele

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Atualizado - Você precisaria editar o elemento `input`. Uma solução alternativa seria incluir a sua própria imagem SVG e mudar a cor do `fill`. Vou compartilhar um exemplo:

```
    input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        background-color: rgba(119, 0, 255, 0.3);
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="15" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="rgb(119, 0, 255)" d="M20 3h-1V1h-2v2H7V1H5v2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v16c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 18H4V8h16v13z"/></svg>');
        background-position: 100% center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: eu cheguei a fazer as duas maneira mas ele continua so mudando a cor do placeholder de DD/MM/AAAA o icone do calendario continua em branco que no fundo branco acaba ficando invisivel

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo, você pode eliminar o background color e o que mais não precisar. Você também pode mudar a cor da fonte inserindo `CSS` direto na tag input. Bom trabalho!